# External merge tool Visual Source Safe 6.0d

Tags: version-control, merge, visual-sourcesafe

Is there a way, using Visual Source Safe 6.0d, to use an external merge utility such as WinMerge. I known VSS 6.0d is kind of old, but I stuck with it.

Note: In VSS 6.0d, there is no "Custom Editors" tab. Otherwise, it would have been too easy.

Comment: Don't see a way to do that in VSS 6.0d either. Seems the feature - configuring external merge tool - is not available till VSS 8.0.

Comment: I found out that VSS 6.0d DB is compatible with VSS 2005 (v8.0). Microsoft states :Visual SourceSafe database format was not changed between Visual SourceSafe 6.0 and Visual SourceSafe 2005. There is no need for conversion tools. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th1ac915%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: So far the only way I have found is to use VSS 2005 to access the VSS 6.0d database. I just have to convinces my employer to get some licenses of VSS 2005, if they still exist, so I can use the Custom Editor feature to resolve the issue. If anyone have a solution, you are more than welcome to share your knowledge.

Comment: You may also consider using a VSS addon tool, like SourceAnywhere for VSS, which allows you to configure an external merge tool.
http://www.dynamsoft.com/help/SAW/COp_External%20Programs%20Options.htm 

(Disclaimer: I work for the company.)